# Measure the time for a component movement in QML

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qt-quick, qtquickcontrols2

In this simple code, the user can drag the *racket* up or downwards. We want to know the time for the *racket* movement (i.e, each *y* changes of the racket caught by *onYChanged*) . If the user moves it fast the time for each *y* change is littler than the time they move it slowly, naturally.

I went for this, but it always writes "Time = 0"! Is there any way for doing this simple task please?

*main.qml*:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12

Window {
    id: window
    visible: true
    width: 700; height: 500
    color: "gray"

    Rectangle {
        id: table
        width: window.width / 1.15; height: window.height / 1.15
        y: 10
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        color: "royalblue"
    }

    Racket {
        id: racket
        x: table.width - 10
        y: table.height / 2
    }
}
```

*Racket.qml*:

```
import QtQuick 2.12

Rectangle {
    width: 15; height: 65

    property int oldY: y
    property bool yUwards: false
    property bool yDwards: false
    property double colTime

    onYChanged: {
         colTime = new Date().getTime()

        if (y > oldY)
            yDwards = true
        else if (y < oldY)
            yUwards = true
        oldY = y
        console.log("Time = ", colTime - new Date().getTime())
    }

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.margins: -parent.height
        drag.target: parent
        drag.axis: Drag.YAxis
        drag.minimumY: table.y
        drag.maximumY: table.height - parent.height + 10
    }
}
```

Comment: If you realize you are only measuring the time of the comparison that is practically 0, what time do you want to measure? Do you want to measure the time from when you begin to drag the racket until you release it?

Comment: Yes, you're right. The user maybe drags it up or downwards for few seconds and then releases it. What I want is the time for each y change of the racket.

Comment: I already understand you, I have a question: in the case that the movement starts up then the time that would be measured is until it is released, but in the case that instead of stopping it moves down quickly which one or which ones are the times you want to measure? Do you want to measure the time between when the racket does not move or when the racket changes direction?

Comment: Sorry, I want the time for any *y* change of the racket regardless of directions or release. For example, the user can drag it upwards, and we suppose for that the *onYChanged* catches five times *y* changes. Then probably the user drags it downwards for a while, and *onYChanged* catches four times *y* changes this time. Now totally up to know we have had nine y changes of the racket. I want the time for each of these 9 times change in the y property of the racket. The times possibly are different because the user may have dragged the racket upwards faster than downwards or vice versa.

Comment: I did not understand, I'm going to put several cases: 1) Drag up and let go, in that case the time you want is the interval between the racket does not move. 2) is dragged up one second and down another 2 seconds without stopping the racket, in the latter case should be shown 1 time, ie the time it enters the rackets are still; or 2 times: t1 -> quiet to change direction, t2 -> change of direction to still ?. Out of the above, even when you move alone upwards, the hand has inertia and therefore it is going to move downwards, which I think can be despised.

Comment: Your edition to your question goes in the opposite direction to your first explanation since you want to measure the time between each change of Y, for example let's say that the racket moves and it is released in so the position say t1 then after a long time t2 the racket moves then do you want the time of stillness?

Comment: Yes, I want the time between/for each change of y. The handler *onYChanged* is called for every point where y changes. So there must be a time for those changes and it's mutable because the user can drag it fast or slowly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188312/discussion-between-franky-and-eyllanesc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to measure the change time, you must do the same procedure as with Y, save the last time in memory:

```
import QtQuick 2.12

Rectangle {
    width: 15; height: 65

    property bool yUwards: false
    property bool yDwards: false
    property real oldY: y
    property double last_time: new Date().getTime()

    onYChanged: {
        var current_time = new Date().getTime()
        console.log("Time = ", current_time - last_time)
        if (y > oldY)
            yDwards = true
        else if (y < oldY)
            yUwards = true
        oldY = y
        last_time = current_time
    }

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.margins: -parent.height
        drag.target: parent
        drag.axis: Drag.YAxis
        drag.minimumY: table.y
        drag.maximumY: table.height - parent.height + 10
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I tested that, but it once again just writes "Time = 0". Don't we have something more precise?

Comment: @Franky I get `qml: Time =  17
qml: Time =  24
qml: Time =  17
qml: Time =  19
qml: Time =  18
qml: Time =  16
qml: Time =  17
qml: Time =  49`

Comment: @Franky Are you sure you are using my code without modifications?

Comment: @Franky yes, maybe you are using a version of Qt that has a bug, I am using Qt 5.12 on Linux

Comment: +1. No, I'm also using 5.12 on Window. I clicked on "run qmake" and it worked now. Thanks you. Just to be sure about the work. When we drag the racket, it moves pixel by pixel, right? And for each of these pixels, the handler *onYChanged* is called. Right up to now?

Comment: @Franky it does not move pixel by pixel, that's inefficient, it moves when necessary. And every time Y changes this flame to onYChanged but if onYChanged a task that takes 1 second and still varies Y, those changes will be lost, so the tasks in onPropertyChanged must be fast.

Comment: @Franky nothing moves pixel by pixel, when you move the mouse the OS only tells the application to change the mouse if the displacement passes a certain threshold, remember that the application is the last element that consumes that event: there is a delay in reading the hardware, another OS, another Qt, and another of your application. If my answer helps you do not forget to mark it as correct, that is the best way to thank.

Comment: OK, so when we get "Time = 10", that means we moved the racket faster than the time when we get "Time = 15". Right?

Comment: @Franky yes, the error is always less than 1 ms so it is correct, obviously this could be false if your application performs more tasks since the Qt event loop will be saturated. Do you need such precision? In general, the error of time that is committed can be disregarded.